# How to set Wallpaper on both home screen and lock screen on button click by using intent and built in library?

Tags: android, firebase

[how to set wallpaper as lockscreen or both(home and lock)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59114620/how-to-set-wallpaper-as-lockscreen-or-bothhome-and-lock)
I use this link. This one is not helpful for me because it uses the separate separate options but i want to do by using built-in means when i click on button it shows the dialog that on home screen lock screen or both
Please help me in this regrad

Comment: I need answer ASAP

Comment: What type of wallpaper it is? gif or image?

Comment: This is too easy man. Show dialog and combine flags then (WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK | WallpaperManager.FLAG_SYSTEM)